# How do I add concurrency limits to a scheduled query in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

1. I monitor my logs for an externally controlled event.
2. The observation of an instance of that externally controlled event triggers a Cloud Function (I intentionally limit the maximum instances of the Cloud Function to 1).

[image: Cloud Function Configuration]

3. The Cloud Function triggers an “on-demand” Scheduled Query in BigQuery.

#### First Preference:

Can I set a limit to the number of active instances of a BigQuery on-demand Scheduled Query to just one (kind of like how I limit the instances of the Cloud Function to just one at a time)?

#### Alternative Possibility:

(If I cannot limit the number of instances directly) Can I limit the the BigQuery on-demand Scheduled Query to not run if it has been triggered less than five minutes ago?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no limit for BigQuery runs, but you can limit the amount per user. So you  have a Cloud Function which runs a BigQuery script. Do you want  the BigQuery script not to run by your cloud function, when it was run less than 5 minutes ago? Then the last run of your Cloud Function must be logged and compared by it before starting the BigQuery script. Logging can be done in Firestore. Logging in BigQuery would result in a 10 MB query for each check.

Comment: Interesting. Your comment is making me think that if it is impossible to prevent multiple simultaneous instances of an on-demand scheduled query, perhaps it is best to simply write the set of queries directly in the python cloud function (bypassing the scheduled query features altogether). Since the cloud function is limited with the auto scaling setting, that effectively prevents the queries from running concurrently.

Comment: Yes, running the query directly in python is a good option. But if you start the query and do not wait in the python cloud function for the finish, there is the possibility that several queries run in parallel. If you wait in python for the finish of the query, you pay for the running time of your cloud function. Also if the cloud function is triggered several times, the function will wait for the finish of the last one and start then. Thus you do not prevent the BigQuery script to run several times.

Comment: I would consider writing the queries in python as an acceptable solution, especially if no one else comes up with a direct solution to the question of how to limit the simultaneous instances of a Scheduled Query.